# Getting java.net.SocketTimeoutException alwayse in downloading files with OkHttp

Tags: android, download, okhttp

I am using OkHttp to download a file from the server.
And this is my code:
I set read and write timeout for it:

```
 public static final String API_BASE_URL = "http://XXXX:8080/tablet/";
    private static OkHttpClient.Builder httpClient = new OkHttpClient.Builder()
      .connectTimeout(60,TimeUnit.SECONDS)
      .writeTimeout(60,TimeUnit.SECONDS);
```

This is my `createServiceFile`:

```
public static <S> S createServiceFile(Class<S> serviceClass, final String token) {
        if (token != null) {

            httpClient.addInterceptor(new Interceptor() {
                @Override
                public Response intercept(Chain chain) throws IOException {
                    Request original = chain.request();
                    Request.Builder requestBuilder = original.newBuilder()
                      .header("Authorization", token)
                      .header("Accept", "text/html,application/xhtml+xml,application/pdf,application/xml;q=0.9," +
                        "image/webp,audio/mpeg ,image/png,audio/mp4,image/jpeg,*/*;q=0.8")
                      .method(original.method(), original.body());
                    Request request = requestBuilder.build();
                    return chain.proceed(request);
                }
            });
        }
        OkHttpClient client = httpClient.build();
        Retrofit retrofit = builder.client(client).build();
        return retrofit.create(serviceClass);
    }
```

And this is my code that I write the response to SD Card (in response contentLength is -1 because the server doesn't send it to me):

```
public DownloadRequest DownloadFile() {

    //Creating folder for Application in SD Card if it's not created yet in App Class!
    new java.io.File(G.DIR_APP).mkdirs();
    new java.io.File(G.DIR_MEDIA).mkdirs();

    APIService downloadService = ServiceGenerator.createServiceFile(APIService.class, G.TOKEN);
    downloadService.downloadFileWithDynamicUrlSync(url)//set URL of the  file
      .subscribeOn(Schedulers.newThread())
      .observeOn(Schedulers.io())
      .delay(30, TimeUnit.MILLISECONDS)
      .subscribe(new Observer<ResponseBody>() {
        @Override
        public void onSubscribe(Disposable d) {

        }

        @Override
        public void onNext(ResponseBody responseBody) {

          Log.i(TAG, "On Next And Current App is: " + fileName);

          if (writeResponseBodyToDisk(responseBody)) {

            Log.i(TAG, fileName + "Downloaded successful");

            //This Download was successful Then try to set downloadResult true
            result = true;

          } else {
            result = false;
          }
        }

        @Override
        public void onError(Throwable e) {

          Log.i(TAG, "!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!\n\nOn Error And Current App is: " +
            fileName + " And Error is" + e.toString() + "\n\n!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!\n\n");

          //Set downloadResult false
          result = false;
          if (listener != null) {
            listener.onDownloadCompleteListener(false);
          }
        }

        @Override
        public void onComplete() {
          Log.i(TAG, "On Complete And Current App is: " + fileName);

          if (listener != null) {
            if (result) {
              listener.onDownloadCompleteListener(true);
            } else {
              listener.onDownloadCompleteListener(false);
            }
          }

        }
      });

    return this;
  }
```

And this code will write response to disck:

```
  private boolean writeResponseBodyToDisk(ResponseBody body) {

    // Location to save downloaded file and filename
    java.io.File file = new java.io.File(destinationPath + fileName + "." + extension);

    try {

      InputStream inputStream = null;
      OutputStream outputStream = null;
      int bytesBuffered = 0;

      try {
        byte[] fileReader = new byte[bufferSize];

        downloadSize = 0;
        inputStream = body.byteStream();

        /*
         * If append requested we have to append new bytes to
         * Exists bytes on the storage
         */
        if (appendNeed) {
          outputStream = new FileOutputStream(file, true);
        } else {
          outputStream = new FileOutputStream(file);
        }

        while (true) {

          int read = inputStream.read(fileReader);
          if (read == -1) {
            break;
          }

          bytesBuffered += read;

          if (bytesBuffered > 1024 * 1024) {
            //  outputStream.write(fileReader, 0, read);
            outputStream.flush();
            bytesBuffered = 0;
          }
          outputStream.write(fileReader, 0, read);
          downloadSize += read;

          percent = (int) (100.0f * (float) downloadSize / totalSize);
          if (listener != null) {
            listener.onDownloadPercentListener(percent);
          }
        }
        outputStream.flush();
        inputStream.close();
        outputStream.close();


        return true;
      } catch (IOException e) {

        Log.i(TAG, "Error in download" + e.toString());
        return false;

      } finally {
        if (inputStream != null) {
          inputStream.close();
        }
        if (outputStream != null) {
          outputStream.close();
        }
      }
    } catch (IOException e) {
      Log.i(TAG, "Error in download" + e.toString());
      return false;
    }
  }
```

But I get false from this method (`writeResponseBodyToDisk`)with error of

`java.net.SocketTimeoutException` while the file is downloaded correctly!
I think this problem it about contentLength that is -1 for me.

Thank you for your answers.

Comment: timeout exception occurs when your process is not completed during the time you specified. So either you need to increase the time you are giving the process to complete or take a look at your service method what is taking that long for it to give the response.

Comment: If there is a timeout then you get no response. So there is no content length either. And there is none in your code either.

Comment: Please show complete code as these snippets make no sense.

Comment: try to set the readTimeOut to 60 sec.

Comment: @greenapps This is Complele code man!

Comment: No. Not complete as we cannot see where and how you call `writeResponseBodyToDisk().

Comment: @greenapps I add it.

Comment: You are nowhere using httpClient.

Comment: @greenapps in createServiceFile I used it!

Comment: ` new java.io.File(G.DIR_APP).mkdirs();`. You are not checking a return value. Or does it throw if the directory cannot be created? Dont call mkdirs if directories already exist.

Comment: And when and where is httpClient created?

Comment: I do not understand your code. And as you did not explain how it should work i can be of little help.

Comment: You are setting *connect* and *write* timeouts. Not 'read and write timeouts'. Whatever read timeout you are settting, by whatever means, including defaulting it, it is too short. Increase it. Or fix your server. NB Your copy loop is about ten times as complex as necessary.

Comment: For example, `FileOutputStream.flush()` does nothing, so all the housekeeping you are doing around it is pointless.